# Use the Fitch System to prove (¬p ⇒ q) ⇒ ((¬p ⇒ ¬q) ⇒ p).

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

```
1.  p                                 Assumption
2.  ~p => ~q                          Assumption
3.  p                                 Reiteration: 1
4. (~p => ~q) => p                    Implication Introduction: 2, 3
5.  ~p => q                           Assumption
6. (~p => ~q) => p                    Reiteration: 4
7. (~p => q) => (~p => ~q) => p       Implication Introduction: 5, 6
```

It does not work in this way. So, I suppose p is not the right assumption...

Could you please help me to define the initial assumption to proceed?

Comment: It is not correct: assumption 1: $p$ is undischarged.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you explain what you mean by derive a contradiction? I don't understand this part of your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seek to prove: $\vdash (\neg p\to q)\to((\neg p\to\neg q)\to p)$

A method to prove $\phi\to (\psi\to \chi)$, would be to assume $\phi$ and $\psi$ then make an argument to conclude $\chi$, then discharge the assumptions with conditional introduction.

So then, can you make an argument for $p$ made under an assumption of $\neg p\to q$ and $\neg p \to\neg q$ ?

$$\begin{array}{r|l:l}
1. & \quad \neg p\to q & \text{Assumption}\\
2. & \qquad \neg p\to\neg q & \text{Assumption}\\
\vdots & \qquad\quad\vdots & \vdots \\
n. & \qquad p & \\
n+1. & \quad (\neg p\to\neg q)\to p&2,n,\text{Conditional Introduction}\\
n+2. & (\neg p\to q)\to((\neg p\to\neg q)\to p)&1,n+1,\text{Conditional Introduction}\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, I don't want to spoil the question but this is how I reached the answer.

1. $\quad\lnot p \to q\hspace{22ex}$Assumption
2. $\qquad\lnot p \to \lnot q\hspace{18ex}$Assumption
3. $\qquad\lnot\lnot p\hspace{23ex}$Negation Introduction: 1, 2
4. $\qquad p\hspace{26ex}$Double Negation Elimination: 3
5. $\quad(\lnot p \to \lnot q) \to p\hspace{14.5ex}$Implication Introduction: 2, 4
6. $((\lnot p \to q) \to ((\lnot p \to \lnot q) \to p)\hspace{1.5ex}$Implication Introduction: 1, 5

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Assume $\lnot p$ and derive both $q$ and $\lnot q$.

Having reached a contradiction, we can use it to derive $\lnot \lnot p$ by $\lnot$-intro, discharging the assumption, and conclude by *Double Negation*.